# Get & Set Object items - chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, object, storage

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(keys) {
  console.log(keys); //Get object with all keys from storage
});
```

Console:
object {
     item1: {
         a: "data1a",
         b: "data1b"
     }
     item2: {
         a: "data2a",
         b: "data2b"
     }
   }

Now, I want to delete item1 from object and save it back using chrome.storage.local.set();

I can able to delete values of key 'item1', for example a & b. How to delete key 'item1' itself?

Comment: `delete keys.item1` ?

Comment: @FelixKling Yeah, I know that it will delete item1. But, problem is after deletion when call chrome.storage.local.set to save object with item2. Any way?

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: It's not replacing existing object in chrome.storage. Could you please write up a chrome.storage.local.set for this.

Comment: It seems what you actually want is `chrome.storage.local.remove('item1')`. See the docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage .

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks! Got it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chrome.storage.local.remove('item1'); //delete key in an object
```

Docs: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage